# Use undirected links instead of Directed links

Tags: performance, simulation, netlogo, multi-agent

In my model I use direct links to keep interaction value of each turtle to other turtles and each link has a different value for each end of the links which is exactly what I want and it was really easy to implement, However, I have a performance issue and my model is not working as fast as I think it should work.

Now I am trying different methods to decrease the computation needs. One of the things that crossed my mind is to integrate all directed links to undirected links and put the value of interaction value of end1 and end2 to each other as links attributes for example *end1-end2-Relationship-Value* and *end2-end1-Relationship-Value* and *Frequency1 Frequency2*. This implementation will make my whole model a bit more difficult to debug since the order of links will be much more difficult to keep track of and I use the calculation of these values a lot, so I was wondering if anyone has a better way to increase the performance :)

The reason I thought this might be better is that It will reduce the number of links to half, another method is forgetting links (kill old links or links with less significant relationship (insignificant relationship value and lower frequency of relationship) but this one is not totally compatible with my model setting.

```
agents-own [Belongs_to My-home popularity ]
patches-own [label_ storage]
links-own[Value-Of-The-Relationship frequency] 

to Update_link_Values  [Self_Agent Other_Agent Value]
 ask Self_Agent 
   [     ifelse any? links with [end1 = Self_Agent and End2 = Other_Agent]

         [ask out-link-to Other_Agent  [ set Value-Of-The-Relationship Value-Of-The-Relationship + Value  set Frequency Frequency + 1 ]  set hidden? true] 
         [create-link-to Other_Agent [set Value-Of-The-Relationship Value-Of-The-Relationship + Value set Frequency Frequency + 1 ] set hidden? true ] 

     ] 

end

to SeTPoPularity
   set Popularity sum[Value-Of-The-Relationship] of links with [end2 = mySelf]
 end
```

**Update 2 :** 
I think I already found a better way (obvious  one! Which I should have done in first place)  to set popularity, instead of calling it every tick I just can update it only if it has changed, I even think I might don't need The variable called "popularity" every time I need it I just call the  **my-in-links**

**Update 3 : **

```
to Update_link_Values  [Self_Agent Other_Agent Value]
     ask Self_Agent 
       [     ifelse out-link-neighbor? Other_Agent

             [ask out-link-to Other_Agent  [ set Value-Of-The-Relationship Value-Of-The-Relationship + Value  set Frequency Frequency + 1 ]  set hidden? true] 
             [create-link-to Other_Agent [set Value-Of-The-Relationship Value-Of-The-Relationship + Value set Frequency Frequency + 1 ] set hidden? true ] 

         ] 

end
```

Thank to Seth for his comments

Thanks .
Marzy.

Comment: After checking the current performance I have noticed that checking patch values is another main performance problem in my simulation, each agent has a My-Home property which stores a patch address and all family members have same my-home value, each patch stores a property value which is owned by whole family members, when population grows and number of people in one patch exceeds 7, the oldest son with his mate (if any) will move out and will transfer his share to new my-home patch, if all family members die, the share  of whole family will be moved to community patch.

Comment: Confused by all the new questions in your updates – maybe open one or more new, separate questions?

Comment: Ok, I just did , I m totally new to Stackoverflow ! Thanks for your inputs :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plan doesn't sound to me like it would help performance. It sounds just as likely to make things slower as faster.

Have you tried using the profiler extension to see which procedures are the ones using the most CPU?  http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/5.0/docs/profiler.html

**UPDATE:** (now that code has been provided)

`links with [end2 = mySelf]` is slow because it has to check every link to see whether it satisfies the given condition. I think you mean `[my-in-links] of myself`; primitives like `my-in-links` return answers immediately, without having to check every link.

Similarly, you have `any? links with [end1 = Self_Agent and End2 = Other_Agent]`. Again, using `with` means every link has to be checked if satisfies the condition. Instead, write `[out-link-neighbor? Other_Agent] of Self_Agent`. `out-link-neighbor?` can check for the existence of a link directly, without having to scan every link.

I have a hunch that eliminating unnecessary uses of `with` will fix your performance problems. But, one additional, less important note:

Why `foreach sort sss`? Why not just `ask sss`? Is there some reason it needs to run in sorted order? `ask` is faster than `foreach` plus `sort` plus `?`.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I have used this extension, currently my simulation for 40000 ticks (10 lifetime for a population of 50-100 agents) which include social interaction of individuals takes 15 - 20 mins on a  win7,32bit,2GB ram ,2.4 ghz CPU). The most CPU is used by 3 procedures, the one which checks which patch does not have any agent living in it and moves the property of that patch to community level, the one which sets agents popularity which is the sum of relationship values of each out-link-neighbor and the one which checks how many agents live in one patch and asks the oldest son to move out.

Comment: If you posted the code for the procedures that are using most of the runtime, I might be able to spot speedup opportunities. (Or not, impossible to know in advance.)

Comment: Yes, you are right :) I will change the code, for now changing [Move out and set popularity] functions that I mentioned in the question improved the performance a lot :)

Comment: Awesome, great to hear!

Answer (score 1):

Just for summarizing the result of what I have done in the first place to change Directed links to  undirected ones which made lots of trouble after that, so I will still use Directed links :

This is the code that I have used:

```
to Update_link_Values  [Self_Agent Other_Agent Value]
 ask Self_Agent 
   [     ifelse  out-link-neighbor? Other_Agent

         [ask out-link-to Other_Agent  [ set Value-Of-The-Relationship Value-Of-The-Relationship + Value  set Frequency Frequency + 1 ]  set hidden? true] ;IF already has a link 
         [create-link-to Other_Agent [set Value-Of-The-Relationship Value-Of-The-Relationship + Value set Frequency Frequency + 1 ] set hidden? true ] ;If they meet for the first time

     ] 

end

;Update_Friendship_Values 
to Update_Friendship_Values  [Self_Agent Other_Agent Value]
  ask Self_Agent 
    [     
      ifelse any? Friendships with [end1 = Self_Agent and End2 = Other_Agent]

      [
        ask Friendships with [end1 = Self_Agent and End2 = Other_Agent] 
        [ 
          set End1-End2-Value-Of-The-Relationship End1-End2-Value-Of-The-Relationship + Value  
          set End1-End2-Frequency End1-End2-Frequency + 1  
        ]  
       ; set hidden? true
      ] ;IF already has a link and first agent is end1
      [  
        ifelse any? Friendships with [end2 = Self_Agent and End1 = Other_Agent]

          [
            ask Friendships with [end2 = Self_Agent and End1 = Other_Agent] 
            [ 
              set End2-End1-Value-Of-The-Relationship End2-End1-Value-Of-The-Relationship + Value  
              set End2-End1-Frequency End2-End1-Frequency + 1
            ]  
            ;set hidden? true
          ] ;IF already has a link and first agent is end2 
          [ ifelse count Other_Agent = 1 
            [create-Friendship-with Other_Agent [
              set End1-End2-Value-Of-The-Relationship End1-End2-Value-Of-The-Relationship + Value
              set End1-End2-Frequency End1-End2-Frequency + 1 
            ]] [
            create-Friendships-with Other_Agent [
              set End1-End2-Value-Of-The-Relationship End1-End2-Value-Of-The-Relationship + Value
              set End1-End2-Frequency End1-End2-Frequency + 1]
            ;set hidden? true 
          ] ]
      ]
    ] 

end
```

With corrections that Seth suggested I think having more links is better than having more complex computation to find right undirected links (here called Friendships)